# How to update only a certain percent of matching values

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a table which contains, apart from other, such fields: `id integer, status_id integer, add_date date`.

I would like to execute a query similar to this:

`update table set status_id = new_status_id where status_id = old_status_id`

but one that would only update a given percent of values, say 50%. Moreover, the distribution of the updated rows for each date should be similar; I want half rows with `date = 23.06.2013` updated and half not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
update table
set status_id = new_status_id
where
    status_id = old_status_id
    and random() < 0.5
```

Comment: The easy one, but will not consider dates. And it can update the whole table (if it is small enough)

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko a not precise update in regard to dates is acceptable, and this query is by far the simplest possible. Hence the accept. I appreciate your work though, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This query will give you `id` of the rows, you want to update:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT id, 
       count(id) OVER (PARTITION BY add_date) cnt, 
       row_num() OVER (PARTITION BY add_date ORDER BY id) rn
FROM table
WHERE status_id = old_status_id) sub
WHERE rn  <= cnt * 0.5 -- your percentage
-- WHERE rn  <= cnt * 0.5 + random() -- another (better) version. 
                                     -- Will update at random if there if only one row
```

Comment: `ORDER BY id` .. it's not in the request to update smaller IDs first. You could just remove the clause to get an arbitrary selection (which would be faster, since both window functions share the same window then) or replace it with `ORDER BY random()` to get a truly random selection.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yes, I know. It is just a habit of adding a `ORDER BY` to a `row_num()` with any arbitrary column (because Oracle will throw an error otherwise). And using `random()` when it may not be required isnt good. (call to `random()` may not be cheap)

Comment: _if it is small enough_ as your comment to my answer then this is also not perfect as none of the dates with one only row will be deleted. Also there is a small error in that `count` and `row_number` both return integers. The solution would be something like `rn::float / cnt`

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Fixed the error (worked too much with Oracle, where this functions return numeric). As for 1, 3, 5 ... other odd amount of rows - you cant update exactly half of them. So any solution will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When laying in bed and trying to sleep a very simple solution came to my mind:

```
update table
set status_id = new_status_id
where
        status_id = old_status_id
    and id % 2 = 0;
```

Since the id is actually a `bigserial`, this query will have similar effect to Clodoaldo's.